# JButton with both ActionListener / MouseListener

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener, mouselistener

Is it possible to create a Jbutton with both an ActionListener and MouseListener

Meaning so i create a button and then when i press it ( throught actionListener) it changes the frame so that AFTER then button was pressed i  can press anywhere on the frame and MouseListener would in use.

```
JButton button = new JButton();//Creates Button
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {         
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Insert MouseListener
    //Then do something with mouseListener
}
});
```

Heres the curent code: however they're now in sync when i try to click the button and i cannot call mouseListener a 2nd time

```
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Click");
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
            newCube.stopCube();
        }

    });
    button2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
        {
            double x = evt.getX();
            double y = evt.getY();
            newCube.setCube(x,y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but what is the purpose for that?

Comment: how would i do that?
the purpose is that suppose i have a frame with 2 buttons one that moves something and the 2nd one stops it and then using mouse listener i can move it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example with `JToggleButton` which add/remove `MouseListener` to `JFrame`.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    private MouseAdapter mouseListener;

    public Example(){
        init();
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                System.out.println("clicked");
            }
        };
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton("add listener");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(((JToggleButton)e.getSource()).isSelected()){
                    Example.this.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
                    ((JToggleButton)e.getSource()).setText("remove listener");
                } else {
                    Example.this.removeMouseListener(mouseListener);
                    ((JToggleButton)e.getSource()).setText("add listener");
                }
            }
        });
        add(b);
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new Example();
    }
}
```

EDIT: examle with `JButton`:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    private MouseAdapter mouseListener;

    public Example(){
        init();
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                System.out.println("clicked");
            }
        };
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton b = new JButton("add listener");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("add listener")){
                    Example.this.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
                    ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("remove listener");
                } else {
                    Example.this.removeMouseListener(mouseListener);
                    ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("add listener");
                }
            }
        });
        add(b);
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new Example();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry im not familar with JToggle so im a little confused is there a simpler way without it?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `JButton` but `JToggleButton` indicates if your `MouseListener` is active.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move something by clicking on it, you can use a mouse listener on that node directly, instead of using it on the button.

To add both the action listener and a mouse listener on a button, you can use the addActionListener and addMouseListener methods on the button.

Look at the api for information about these methods... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html

Comment: tried adding both but mouseListener would always work in sync with actionListener

Comment: You can use a boolean variable to toggle between the mouse listener.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this sample might help you (add this to your own ActionListener)

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ((JButton)e.getSource()).addMouseListener(yourMouseListener);
}
```

I tried this, it works.

Comment: what is yourMouseListener? a public void method?

Comment: it can be anything that implements MouseListener interface (especially new MouseListener(){ //MouseListener body with overrided methods }

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is still not clear to me. Though this can help you. It will add a mouse listner to the component when the start button is clicked and remove the mouse listner when stop button is clicked. Thus you can stop the two listeners from working in sync..

```
JButton startButton = new JButton();

startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {         
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   //Add MouseListener to move the component

}
}); 

JButton stopButton = new JButton();

stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {         
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   //Remove the MouseListener

}
});
```