# Minesweeper Java Inheritance

Tags: java, minesweeper

I have 5 classes for this project, `Button`  `Minefield` `GUI` `MenuBar` `Game`.

`Button` is an individual mine cell.

`Minefield` contains a 2d array of buttons, and operations that concern all of the buttons.

`GUI` is the portion above the MineField grid, displaying the reset button, time lapsed and how many flags remain,

`Game` puts all of the other classes in Panels and places them in the applet. No game logic here.

Here is a screenshot of my [applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8ycE.png)

I'm having problems when it comes to using inheritance. If I can solve this issue, I can do the other problems too. It has to do with invoking a method in the super class.

**One of my problems:**

When a `Button` mine cell is right-clicked, the mouse listener picks it up and changes the text of the `JButton` to "F" for flag. However, I want to update the counter of how many flags are available, which is a variable in the `Minefield` class. Finally, I want the `GUI` class to listen for changes to that variable and update the `JLabel`.

In the `MouseListener` for `Button`:

```
 if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
        {
           advanceCurrentState();     

           if (currentState == "FLAG")
             super.setNumFlagsRemaining(-1); //update the Minefields variable
        }
```

Back in `Minefield`:

```
   public void setNumFlagsRemaining(int delta)
    {
        numFlagsRemaining += delta;
    }
```

But this doesn't work. When I am debugging, `super.setNumFlagsRemaining(-1)` is creating a new instance of `Minefield` and I cannot update the variable inside the super class. I thought that it would update the existing object of Minefield, but  I read that Java does not pass by reference, so I was confused as how to do it. If you need to see additional code please say so, I tried to not clutter this post with 5 whole classes and say, "fix it".

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348685/jbutton-with-both-actionlistener-mouselistener

Comment: Calling `super.setNumFlagsRemaining(-1)` is not creating a new Minefield instance, it is updating the current one. Any use of the word _super_ in a class is referring to the same instance, but as it's parent type.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that `Button` extends `Minefield`, but at the same time `Minefield` contains a 2D array of `Button`s?

Comment: Why would you do that? Tbh `Button` shouldn't extend `Minefield`. If you have whole game logic in `Minefield` then every `Button` will handle/modify its own game logic...? I don't understand this hierarchy...

Comment: Well, the way I was thinking it was : the Minefield class is used only to place the random mines at start, and to go through each Button and count the adjacent mines, storing that information inside of that Button's instance. The Button is just changing its state and has a boolean isMine

Comment: `if (currentState == "FLAG")` Don't use == to compare Strings; it will eventually fail. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java .

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide enough code so I can only guess here.
I think you are confused with [key word super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) 
It actually mean to call method from the super class which you had inherited.
I doubt that JButton inherits anything from your class Minefield. Usually it is in opposite way.

Also count of the fields is stored and displayed in the JLabel. So you, actually, have to call method of the class which has this JLabel and takes care of total count.